# org-cdlatex template expansion does not work the second time

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have extended org-cdlatex-mode to expand the `pmatrix` environment using `pma` as my keyword (config below). This works perfectly the first time I want to insert a pmatrix, but not the second time within the same math environment.

Consider the following example:

```
\begin{align}
pma
\end{align}
```

If I press the TAB key with the cursor after `pma`, I get the wanted expansion

```
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}

\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
```

However, if I want to insert a second `pmatrix` environment, it does not work:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x & y
\end{pmatrix}
=
pma
\end{align}
```

Pressing the TAB key at the end of the `pma` line only moves the cursor forward to the end of the next line.

Can someone explain why and suggest a fix?

Emacs version 24.4.1, Org mode 8.2.10. 

EDIT: Same behaviour for Org mode 9.0.9.

EDIT #2: I get the same behaviour for default template expansions, e.g. `fr`.

Content of minimal `.emacs`:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'turn-on-org-cdlatex)

(setq cdlatex-env-alist
      '(("pmatrix" "\\begin{pmatrix}\n?\n\\end{pmatrix}" nil)))

(setq cdlatex-command-alist
      '(("pma" "Insert pmatrix env" "" cdlatex-environment ("pmatrix") nil t)))
```

Comment: I also encountered this problem. It seems to appear every time an environment is used inside a math environment. The org function that checks whether the point is in a LaTeX math fragment and thus enables the cdlatex functionality is `org-inside-LaTeX-fragment-p`. I didn't dig into it but I guess since there is an `\end{}` statement before point, the cdlatex functionality is disabled. As a workaround, you can edit the formula in a special edit-buffer by invoking `C-c '`.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem, although not a complete answer but a hint on how to solve it:
Have you tried typing "equ" and then do `M-x cdlatex-tab`.
In my case this works, as stated in the cdlatex documentary. It seems that TAB is not bound to "cdlatex-tab" in my case.

Comment: This does not work for me. Both "normal" tab, and the `M-x cdlatex-tab` simply complete the work `equation` but do not enter the equation environment